# Send notification after some time from cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

When a new record is added in Firestore it will hit the create event and send the notification. I want to send that notification after 30 mins of creation.

Comment: what about node-cron?

Comment: I want to use cron jobs but not sure how to use it. Anytime a new record can be created and after 30 min of creation I have to send it.

Comment: https://medium.com/@earlg3/google-cloud-functions-scheduled-trigger-915b5fb8310f

Comment: Also try this https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/functions-cron

Comment: and https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull